# Applying Class to Elements With Attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to apply a class to all elements that have the attribute "state" equals to "disabled". I'm going through each of the elements that have ".overlay" and checking the state and then appending the class "disabledClass" when the attribute "state" is "disabled". Problem is that its applying "disabledClass" on all of the elements. I'm guessing it has something to do with my usage of $(this) in $(this).find(".navElement").addClass("disabledClass"); ?

HTML:

```
<div id="1" class="overlay" state="active">
    <div class="navElement">
        <p>About us</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="2" class="overlay" state="disabled">
    <div class="navElement">
        <p>Our values</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="3" class="overlay" state="disabled">
    <div class="navElement">
        <p>The founder</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(".overlay").click(function () {
    $(".overlay").attr("state", "disabled");
    $(this).attr("state", "active");

    $(".overlay").each(function () {
        if ($(".overlay").attr("state") == "disabled") {
            $(this).find(".navElement").addClass("disabledClass");
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: state is not a valid attribute, you should be using data-* attributes, and then the answers would change

Comment: @adeneo That doesn't *really* matter in this case.

Comment: @VisioN - that's why it's a **comment**, the markup is invalid, and changing the markup could change the answers, especially as `data()` is more commonly used with data attributes.

Comment: And as another sidenote, setting active state is more commonly done with classes, but whatever floats your goat !

Comment: @adeneo I just didn't get this sentence *"and then the answers would change"*.

Comment: @VisioN - Yeah, that was a little unclear, but I meant that using data attributes could change the methods used in the answers etc. And we see this all the time, setting active state on click etc. and it's almost always done with classes to make it styleable, and that would change the answers further, and it makes no sense to check a invalid attribute to set a class in a loop ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
  $(".overlay").click(function(){
        $(".overlay").attr("state", "disabled");
        $(this).attr("state", "active");

        $(".overlay").each(function(){
                if($(this).attr("state") == "disabled"){ //changed this
                $(this).find(".navElement").addClass("disabledClass");
            }
        });

    });
```

Comment: You should highlight that you've changed the `if` condition to `$(this). ...`, otherwise it is very hard to see the difference.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, but I don't really get your question, i.e. what you want to know...

But probably this helps:
Using jQuery to look for all DOM elements with class `overlay` and the attribute `state` set to `disabled` and then append the class `disabledClass` to it's child that contains already the class `navElement` this simple statement should do the trick:

```
$(".overlay[state='disabled']").find(".navElement").addClass("disabledClass")
```